# inline=0 not working for user

Tags: apex

I have an embedded visualforce page on a parent object. On this VF page I have a button that calls the method below. When I click the button the child objecct opens. When I switch to another user, clicking this same button opens the child object within the iFrame where the embedded VF page was located on the parent.

Why is this ??  I am setting inline=0 to prevent the objects from opening in the iFrame.

```
public with sharing class CreateSample {

@TestVisible private Apexpages.StandardController controller;

    public CreateSample(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){
    this.controller = standardController;
    }

    // New approach to open embedded VF page using jscript on vf page

    public String getNewSample () {    

    //do not redirect if an error message exist. Visualforce page will display message. 
    if (ApexPages.hasMessages()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Need to open url passing parm AccId (id of Audit) in this form: /apex/PROD_Audit_Auto_PolicySample?AccId=a06J0000009rp5Y
    Audit__c audit = (Audit__c)controller.getRecord();    
    PageReference pr = Page.PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample;
    pr.getParameters().put('AccId', audit.Id);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr.getURL();
    }

    public void SaveBeforeNew()
    {
        controller.save();
    }

//New approach to open sample in same tab.

public PageReference CreateNewSample() {
        PageReference pageRef = null;

        try { 
            Audit__c audit = (Audit__c)controller.getRecord();  
            pageRef = Page.PROD_V2_Audit_Auto_PolicySample;     
            pageRef.getParameters().put('inline','0'); 
            pageRef.getParameters().put('AccId', audit.Id);
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);            
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }

        return pageRef;
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this jscript to the end of the embedded visualforce page and removed the line setting in the extended controller ; pageRef.getParameters().put('inline','0');

Still when I click on the command button in the embedded vf page it opened the child object up in the iFrame and not as a top window.

In my case the embedded visualforce page is opening a child using the window.top.location.href. Need to do this to break out of the iFrame . Then setting inline  = 0 in the child controllers I am returned to the parent without any scrambling of the pages opened in the iFrame.

Here the command button on the embedded visualforce page on the parent.

```
<script>

    function redirect()
    {
        var url = "{!NewSample}";
        if(url != "null")
            //window.open(url, "_blank");
           window.top.location.href=url;

    }

</script>

<apex:commandButton value="New Audit Sample" action="{!SaveBeforeNew}" reRender="buttons" oncomplete="redirect()" style="background:lightblue;color:blue" id="button1" rendered="{!audit.Audit_Sample_Type__c='Personal Auto'}"/>
```

Here the methods in the child extended controller that either exit or save and return the user back to the parent. Seems to work fine.

```
//save and return user back to the audit .

    public PageReference saveAndReturn() {
        PageReference pageRef = null;

        try {
            PageReference saveRef = stdController.save();
            if (saveRef != null) { 
                    pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.Audit.Id);
                    pageRef.getParameters().put('inline','0');
                    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }

        return pageRef;
    }


    //just return user back to the audit .

    public PageReference ReturnMe() {
        PageReference pageRef = null;

        try {              
              pageRef = new PageReference('/' + this.Audit.Id);
              pageRef.getParameters().put('inline','0'); 
              pageRef.setRedirect(true);            
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }

        return pageRef;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think SFDC adds the inline parameter regardless of the value being set.

Try the following:

1. Do not explicitly set the inline parameter. Sometimes this should fix the issue.
2. Add this java-script code at the end of your VF page within `<script>` tags.

   ```
   var url = location.href;

   var match = url.match(/inline=1/);

   if (match != null) 
   { 
       var newUrl = url.replace(/inline=1/, '');   
       window.top.location=newUrl;

   }
   ```

Comment: This is the simplest way of achieving this